# Clarification on Lemma 68.5 of Munkres

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, free-product

In James R. Munkres's "Topology" he has the lemma

"**Lemma 68.5.** Let $\{G_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in J}$ be a family of groups; let $G$ be a group; let $i_{\alpha}: G_{\alpha} \to G$ be a family of homomorphisms. If the extension condition of Lemma $68.3$ holds, then each $i_{\alpha}$ is a monomorphism and $G$ is the free product of the groups $i_{\alpha}(G_{\alpha})$."

"**Lemma 68.3.** Let $\{G_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in J}$ be a family of groups; let $G$ be a group; let $i_{\alpha}: G_{\alpha} \to G$ be a family of homomorphisms.  If each $i_{\alpha}$ is a monomorphism and $G$ is the free product of the groups $i_{\alpha}(G_{\alpha})$, then $G$ satisfies the following condition:

Given a group $H$ and family of homomorphisms $h_{\alpha}: G_{\alpha} \to H$, there exists a homomorphism $h: G\to H$ such that $h \circ i_{\alpha}=h_{\alpha}$ for each $\alpha$.

Furthermore h is unique."

The proof of **Lemma 68.5.** uses the following lemma

"**Lemma 68.4.** Let $\{G_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in J}$ be a family of groups. Suppose $G$ and $G'$ are groups and $i_{\alpha}: G_{\alpha} \to G$ and $i_{\alpha}': G_{\alpha} \to G'$ are families of monomorphisms such that the families $\{i_{\alpha}(G_{\alpha})\}$ and $\{i_{\alpha}(G_{\alpha}')\}$ generate $G$ and $G'$, respectively. If both $G$ and $G'$ have the extension property stated in the preceding lemma, then there is a unique isomorphism $\phi: G\to G'$ such that $\phi \circ i_{\alpha} = i_{\alpha}'$ for all $\alpha$."

My question is whether the statement of **Lemma 68.5.** is missing the additional assumption that the family $\{i_{\alpha}(G_{\alpha})\}$ generates $G$? Or is that implicitly implied by the condition in **Lemma 68.3.**?

Comment: No, the extension property is not enough (just think of trivial groups $G_\alpha$ as an extreme example); he just forgot the generation condition.

Comment: @MoisheCohen: If $G$ has the extension property for the trivial groups $G_\alpha$, then $G$ has to be trivial. Otherwise take $H:=G$, then $h$ is *not* unique.

Comment: The extension property is enough. If $G$ is the free product and $H$ has the extension property, then one can show (using the extension property in both directions) that $G$ can be seen as subgroup of $H$ and $H$ is the semi-direct product between the kernel of the map from $H$ to $G$ and $G$ as subgroup of $H$.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to what the *extension property* means. If it includes the uniqueness of $h$, then the extension property itself is enough. Otherwise it's not.

Based on the phrasing of Theorem 68.4, it is reasonable to assume that *extension property* does not include the uniqueness of $h$.

So Munkres really should have added the additional assumption as you suggested.